# How do i remove a .limit() that is already applied to a query object

Tags: sqlalchemy

**question: How do i remove a .limit() that is already applied to a query object.**

I have a Query which already has .limit(N) applied. Then i would like to remove the limit from the query, to have a .order_by applied. Order by has to be applied before any limit or offset.

example which fails:

```
query = session.query(Object).limit(10)
query = query.order_by(Object.field)
```

I tried doing:

```
query = session.query(Object).limit(10)
query = query.limit(None) # or False
query = query.order_by(Object.field)
```

But that does not work.

The reason i want this, is that the limit actually happens at another place as a sensible default limit.

Thanks

Comment: the answer you accepted is great, but you may want to factor out that logic into some sort of a "query settings" class.  Not sure what your specific situation is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`limit(None)` will cancel the limit.   If that's not working, you might be on a super-old version of SQLAlchemy perhaps, I tested it all the way back to 0.6.8:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

s = Session()

q = s.query(A).limit(5)

q = q.limit(None).order_by(A.id)

print q
```

Comment: For anyone who ended up here due to a function besides `limit`, most SQLAlchemy functions seem to behave in this same manner.  For instance, I needed to strip an `order_by` clause - `q.order_by(None)` worked beautifully.

Comment: @bsplosion `.filter()` however doesn't behave this way, but I discovered that it is possible to use `.filter(*[])` to not add any filter and I found it useful to make in-line conditional: 
`.filter(*([self.model.search_vector.match(query)] if query else []))`